# Azure Function Singleton with Token

Tags: c#, azure, http, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api

Trying to determine the best calling pattern to use with an Azure Function that contains a HttpClient which contains an auth token in the header.

I can use an AsyncLazy to avoid inflation of the HttpClient. However, I'm worried about the thread-safety of the token.

The current plan is to use a Durable function and an Orchestrater that locks. Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Functions supports dependency injection, so your function's class can receive an instance of `HttpClient` or `IHttpClientFactory` - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests. This is the recommended way to instantiate HttpClients, rather than managing them yourself.

Regarding the token, if it never changes then you can use `IHttpClientFactory` and configure it to create an `HttpClient` with the token added to `DefaultRequestHeaders`. If it does change then I'd suggest using an `HttpRequestMessage` with the header included to send your requests rather than applying it directly to the `HttpClient`.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. Looking into this now. In my case, the Token does change depending on which client calls the Function. Thus, the need for the following HTTP calls to be locked for that instance.